# How to know what version of cross compiler I am using on YOCTO?

Tags: compilation, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, yocto, toolchain

I am using **Yocto** project to build Linux distribution for my embedded board. After the build, I needed to use a **cross compiler** to compile applications from my host machine to be executed on my board.I have just entered the command `bitbake meta-toolchain`. Now I can compile code of applications that are intendent to run on my board on my host machine. I just want to know what is the name and what version of compiler I am using when doing so? how can I know this ? Is there a way to know more information about the toolchain which was build ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, since `meta/recipes-devtools/gcc` contains the available cross-compiler versions but no information about the one that is being built, you can check the current cross-compiler version by executing the following commands:

```
bitbake -e | grep "^GCCVERSION="
```

In order to check out the build system's toolchain configuration, you can refer to the variable `TCMODE` (it should be set in the distro configuration file; e.g. `poky.conf`), you can retrieve its actual value by issuing the commands below:

```
bitbake -e | grep "^TCMODE="
```

Then, you will find the `GCCVERSION`, along with the rest of the toolchain configuration variables, in `poky/meta/conf/distro/include/tcmode-${TCMODE}.conf`. Note that the variables inside the aforementioned file can be overwritten or reassigned in other configuration files such as `conf/local.conf` (that's why `bitbake -e` should be used to retrieve its real value instead).

### In the case you are using the SDK

If you're using the Yocto-generated SDK, you can just execute `<cross-compiler> --version`, e.g.:

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
```

To check the name of the cross-compiler that is being used in your build system, you can:

```
bitbake -e | grep "^export CC="
```

For further information refer to https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#dev-debugging-viewing-variable-values

Comment: Yes I have build SDK to cross compile my application executing this command : ` bitbake meta-toolchain` To check the name of cross compiler I am using : `bitbake -e | grep "^export CC="` It shows me : `export CC="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a5 --sysroot=/home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/defaultpkgname/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot"` To check the version of Cross cmpiler I taped this : `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version` but It tells me : `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found`

Comment: Have you installed the SDK properly? Have you sourced the SDK environment setup script? If so, just type `${CC} --version`

Comment: It works now. I didn't source the SDK environment lately. Now i executed `${CC} --version` And It shows me this : `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`  I have noticed that it is the same version I have found in `meta/recipes-devtools/gcc`  Thank you my friend.

Comment: Nice! You're welcome. I guess you're using Sumo; depending on your Yocto version there can be more than one gcc version available for building your image with!

Answer (score 2):

First, ideally write a recipe to build your application instead of building it by hand.

The compiler is GCC, so you can see what version it is by looking in `meta/recipes-devtools/gcc`.

Comment: So when i need to compile a file, i should write, for exemple : " gcc -c main.cpp " instead of " g++ -c main.cpp " in the Makefile ?

Comment: `g++` and `gcc` are just the C++ and C frontends for GCC.